# How to extract text before the last "," in excel formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to produce a formula that can extract a text before that last comma.

for example:

Let's say in Cell A1 the cell has this: "A100, B100, C100, D100"

I want a formula on Cell B1 that returns the value: "C100"

I was able to produce two formulas that don't do this exactly but think a slight adjustment might do the trick.

1st Formula will return the value after the last comma i.e. "D100"

```
=MID(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",CHAR(1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))+1,LEN(A1))
```

2nd Formula will return everything before the last comma i.e. "A100, B100, C100"

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(A1,FIND("=",SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","=",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))))-1),"")
```

Does anyone know what adjustment is needed to get "C100"?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `FILTERXML()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B1`

```
=FILTERXML("<m><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ","</b><b>")&"</b></m>","//b[last()-1]")
```

---

You can read more on `FILTERXML()` a thoroughly researched and examples shown by **[JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv)** Sir.

**[Excel - Extract substring(s) from string using FILTERXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837696/excel-extract-substrings-from-string-using-filterxml)**

---

You can try this as well,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `C1`

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ",REPT(" ",100)),(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","")))*100-99,100))
```

---

One more way using of `TEXTSPLIT()`

[image]

---

```
=INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A1,,", "),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","")))
```

---

Answer (score 3):

With ms365:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=@TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(A1,,", "),-2)
```